# DraftJS React-Hook-Form - submitting Editor as input

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, draftjs, react-hook-form

I'm working with react-hook-form and I want to pass a rich text editor as input. I've included the RichText component below which is a standard Draft-js implementation, but when I click submit, I get "draft: undefined" instead of the text inside the editor

index.js
import { useForm, Controller } from 'react-hook-form';

```
const JobPostForm = () => {

    const { register, handleSubmit, errors, control } = useForm({
    });

    return(
        <Controller
            as={<RichText />}
            name="draft"
            control={control}
        />
    )
}
```

RichText.js

```
<Editor
      customStyleMap={styleMap}
      ref={editor}
      editorState={editorState}
      onChange={editorState => setEditorState(editorState)}
 />
```

Comment: I think it's hard to reproduce your problem and then help you. Could you please create a demo using, for example, codesandbox and attach a link on the demo in your question?

Comment: Sure @AlexeyKorkoza here is a Sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/interesting-chatterjee-o5x41

Comment: @AlexeyKorkoza also edited again just now.

Answer (score 2):

https://react-hook-form.com/api#Controller

I have updated the doc to include draft-js example:

https://codesandbox.io/s/react-hook-form-v6-controller-qsd8r?file=/src/index.js

you should use Controller's `render` prop

```
import React from "react";
import { Controller } from "react-hook-form";
import { Editor } from "draft-js";

function RichText({ control }) {
  return (
    <div
      style={{
        border: "1px solid #ccc",
        minHeight: 30,
        padding: 10
      }}
    >
      <Controller
        name="DraftJS"
        control={control}
        render={({ value, onChange }) => (
          <Editor editorState={value} onChange={onChange} />
        )}
      />
    </div>
  );
}

export default RichText;
```

Comment: Thanks Bill. I've updated the CodeSandBox to try and match this, but still getting an error "TypeError: Cannot read property 'isOnChange' of undefined". Here is the CodeSandbox:

https://codesandbox.io/s/amazing-kapitsa-2fwjd

Comment: Just checking here if you can customise value, and onchange. In my CodeSandbox they're both custom and I'm having a hard time putting it in the format above. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Just adding to the answer posted by @Bill I would recommend using  `onEditorStateChange` as the prop for the `Editor` component instead of `onChange`. This is why you are getting this error

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'isOnChange' of undefined".

Here is the updated code:

```js
import React from "react";
import { Controller } from "react-hook-form";
import { Editor } from "draft-js";

function RichText({ control }) {
  return (
    <div
      style={{
        border: "1px solid #ccc",
        minHeight: 30,
        padding: 10
      }}
    >
      <Controller
        name="DraftJS"
        control={control}
        render={({ value, onChange }) => (
          <Editor editorState={value} onEditorStateChange={onChange} />
        )}
      />
    </div>
  );
}

export default RichText;
```