# How to integrate Lexical with React-Hook-Form for submitting Editor as input

Tags: reactjs, text-editor, react-hook-form, rich-text-editor, lexicaljs

When I try to make a blog, I can't pass the editor in the form. I found this:

[DraftJS React-Hook-Form - submitting Editor as input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63122422/draftjs-react-hook-form-submitting-editor-as-input)

but it seems that LexicalRichTextEditor does not have such a tag to pass. Can anyone help me?
How can I pass properties to achieve the Add Content and Modify Content functionality?

```
type LexicalEditorProps = {
    //config: Parameters<typeof LexicalComposer>["0"]["initialConfig"];
    content: any;
};

export default function MyEditor(props: LexicalEditorProps) {
    const [ editor ] = useLexicalComposerContext();
    const editorStateRef = useRef();
    const [saveContent, setSaveContent] = useState('');
    const editorConfig: any = {
        // The editor theme
        theme: EditorTheme,
        // Handling of errors during update
        onError(error: any) {
            throw error;
        },
        editorState: props.content,
        // Any custom nodes go here
        nodes: [
            HeadingNode,
            ListNode,
            ListItemNode,
            QuoteNode,
            CodeNode,
            CodeHighlightNode,
            TableNode,
            TableCellNode,
            TableRowNode,
            AutoLinkNode,
            LinkNode
        ]
    };

    useEffect(()=>{
        if(editorStateRef.current){
            setSaveContent(JSON.stringify(editorStateRef.current));
        }
        editor.update(()=>{
            const root = $getRoot();
            const selection = $getSelection();
            const paragraphNode = $createParagraphNode();
            const textNode = $createTextNode(saveContent);

            paragraphNode.append(textNode);
            root.append(paragraphNode);

        });
    },[saveContent]);
    return (
        <LexicalComposer initialConfig={editorConfig}>
            <div className="editor-container">
                <ToolbarPlugin />
                <div className="editor-inner">
                    <RichTextPlugin
                        contentEditable={<ContentEditable className="editor-input" />}
                        placeholder={<Placeholder />}
                        ErrorBoundary={LexicalErrorBoundary}
                    />
                    <OnChangePlugin onChange={(editorState:any) => editorStateRef.current = editorState} />
                    <HistoryPlugin />
                    <AutoFocusPlugin />
                    <CodeHighlightPlugin />
                    <ListPlugin />
                    <LinkPlugin />
                    <AutoLinkPlugin />
                    <ListMaxIndentLevelPlugin maxDepth={7} />
                    <MarkdownShortcutPlugin transformers={TRANSFORMERS} />
                </div>
            </div>
        </LexicalComposer>
    );
}

export function MyForm(){
 const {register, handleSubmit, control, formState: {errors}} = useForm();
    const onSubmit = ( data:any) => {      
        console.log(data);
    };
 return (
   <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)}>
                <Stack spacing={2}>                                      
                    <Card>
                        <Controller control={control} name="content" render={()=> (
                            <MyEditor content={dataSet.content} />
                        )} />
                    </Card>
                    <Box>
                        <Button variant="contained" type="submit">Save</Button>
                    </Box>
                </Stack>
            </form>
 );
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I got the solution, but it's not my doing, it's the great others who helped me with the problem and hopefully will help others.
https://codesandbox.io/s/purple-water-xf50bi?file=/src/App.tsx

UPDATE: Remove the if (editorRef.current ! == undefined) statement and just append field content to data

```
export default function App() {
  const schema = yup
    .object({
      title: yup.string().required(),
      category: yup.string().required(),
      tags: yup.array().required()
    })
    .required();
  const { register, handleSubmit } = useForm({
    resolver: yupResolver(schema)
  });

  //Get Editor State
  const editorRef: any = useRef();
  const onSubmit = (data: any) => {
    data.content= JSON.stringify(editorRef.current.getEditorState())
    console.log(data);
  };
  
  //if (editorRef.current !== undefined) {
  // if (editorRef.current !== null) {
  //    const latestEditorState = editorRef.current.getEditorState();
  //    const textContent = latestEditorState.read(() =>
  //      //You could change getTextContent() for your purpose
  //      $getRoot().getTextContent()
  //    );
  //    console.log(textContent);
  //  }
  //}
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)}>
        <Stack spacing={2}>
          <input {...register("title")} type="text" placeholder="Title" />
          <input {...register("category")} type="text" placeholder="Category" />
          <input type="" placeholder="Tags" />
          <select {...register("tags")} id="tags" multiple>
            <option value="nginx">nginx</option>
            <option value="java">java</option>
            <option value="react">react</option>
            <option value="mui">mui</option>
          </select>
          <Card elevation={3}>
            <MyEditor ref={editorRef} />
          </Card>
          <button type="submit">Save</button>
        </Stack>
      </form>
    </div>
  );
}
```

MyEditor.tsx

```
function Placeholder() {
  return <div className="editor-placeholder">Enter some rich text...</div>;
}

const editorConfig: any = {
  // The editor theme
  theme: EditorTheme,
  // Handling of errors during update
  onError(error: any) {
    throw error;
  },
  // Any custom nodes go here
  nodes: [
    HeadingNode,
    ListNode,
    ListItemNode,
    QuoteNode,
    CodeNode,
    CodeHighlightNode,
    TableNode,
    TableCellNode,
    TableRowNode,
    AutoLinkNode,
    LinkNode
  ]
};

// ADDED THIS:
const EditorCapturePlugin = React.forwardRef((props: any, ref: any) => {
  const [editor] = useLexicalComposerContext();
  useEffect(() => {
    ref.current = editor;
    return () => {
      ref.current = null;
    };
  }, [editor, ref]);

  return null;
});

export const MyEditor = React.forwardRef((props: any, ref: any) => {
  return (
    <LexicalComposer initialConfig={editorConfig}>
      <div className="editor-container">
        <ToolbarPlugin />
        <div className="editor-inner">
          <RichTextPlugin
            contentEditable={<ContentEditable className="editor-input" />}
            placeholder={<Placeholder />}
            ErrorBoundary={LexicalErrorBoundary}
          />
          {/* ADDED THIS: */}
          <EditorCapturePlugin ref={ref} />
          <HistoryPlugin />
          <AutoFocusPlugin />
          <CodeHighlightPlugin />
          <ListPlugin />
          <LinkPlugin />
          <AutoLinkPlugin />
          <ListMaxIndentLevelPlugin maxDepth={7} />
          <MarkdownShortcutPlugin transformers={TRANSFORMERS} />
        </div>
      </div>
    </LexicalComposer>
  );
});
```

Comment: I have the contnent in the schema and it is required, do you have a solution to display the error message if the content is empty?

Comment: Maybe it is features of RHF, add `formState{ errors }` to useForm, please following RHF guild

Answer (score 2):

Not pretty but it works great, in this case I need to store both the editorState (to be able to edit the field after saving it in the db) and the content itself in html

```
  <Controller
    control={control}
    name={`${fieldName}.payload.content`}
    render={({ field: fieldContent }) => (
      <Controller
        control={control}
        name={`${fieldName}.payload.editorState`}
        render={({ field: fieldEditorState }) => (
          <RichText
            background={backgroundColor}
            placeholder={t('create-campaign-form:create-text-for-campaign')}
            onChange={value => {
              fieldEditorState.onChange(value.editorState)
              fieldContent.onChange(value.content)
            }}
            value={fieldEditorState.value}
          />
        )}
      />
    )}
  />
```

The properties `value` and `onChange` are used like so

```js
    // RichText.tsx
    const RichText = ({
      placeholder = '',
      onChange,
      value,
      background,
    }: EditorProps) => {
      const placeholderElement = <PlaceholderElement placeholder={placeholder} />
      const [floatingAnchorElem, setFloatingAnchorElem] =
        useState<HTMLDivElement | null>(null)
    
      const onRef = (_floatingAnchorElem: HTMLDivElement) => {
        if (_floatingAnchorElem !== null) {
          setFloatingAnchorElem(_floatingAnchorElem)
        }
      }
    
      const initialConfig: InitialConfigType = {
        namespace: 'RichTextEditor',
        nodes: [...Nodes],
        onError: (error: Error) => {
          throw error
        },
        theme,
        ...(value && {
          editorState: typeof value !== 'string' ? JSON.stringify(value) : value,
        }),
      }
    
      return (
        <LexicalComposer initialConfig={initialConfig}>
          <ToolbarPlugin />
          <EditorContainer background={background}>
            <LexicalAutoLinkPlugin />
            <RichTextPlugin
              contentEditable={
                <EditorScroller>
                  <EditorWrapper ref={onRef}>
                    <ContentEditable className={'ContentEditable__root'} />
                  </EditorWrapper>
                </EditorScroller>
              }
              placeholder={placeholderElement}
              ErrorBoundary={null}
            />
            <LinkPlugin />
            <ClickableLinkPlugin />
            {floatingAnchorElem && (
              <FloatingLinkEditorPlugin anchorElem={floatingAnchorElem} />
            )}
          </EditorContainer>
          <OnChangePlugin onChange={onChange} />
        </LexicalComposer>
      )
    }
```

```js
// plugins/onChange.tsx
interface onChangePluginProps {
  onChange: (...event: any[]) => void
}

export default function OnChangePlugin({
  onChange,
}: onChangePluginProps): JSX.Element {
  return (
    <LexicalOnchangePlugin
      onChange={(editorState: EditorState, editor: LexicalEditor) => {
        editorState.read(() => {
          const htmlString = $generateHtmlFromNodes(editor, null)
          onChange({ content: htmlString, editorState })
        })
      }}
    />
  )
}
```

Comment: This is a comprehensive solution. I just added `register: {value: $getRoot().getTextContent() }` to my solution by adding